# How to properly specify a signature for numba JIT functions?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy, numba

I created a `@jit` compiled function, which should be faster than a normal loop.
howerver it isnt, since just in time compilation takes minutes. What am I doing wrong?

What is the most efficient way to specify signatures for this function?

```
''' reproducable sample data '''

import numpy as np, time, numba as nb
LEN, Amount_Of_Elements = 10000,4000
temp = np.random.randint(Amount_Of_Elements*0.7,high=Amount_Of_Elements, size=LEN) 
RatiosUp         = [np.random.uniform(size=rand) for rand in temp]
RatiosDown       = [np.random.uniform(size=rand) for rand in temp]
UpPointsSlices   = [np.random.uniform(size=rand) for rand in temp]
DownPointsSlices = [np.random.uniform(size=rand) for rand in temp]

''' function '''

@nb.jit
def filter(a,b):
    return a > b 

@nb.jit
def func(RatiosUp, RatiosDown, UpPointsSlices, DownPointsSlices, result):
    for i in range(len(RatiosUp)): 
   
        for j in range(RatiosUp[i].size): 

            if filter3(RatiosUp[i][j],RatiosDown[i][j]):
                result[i][j] = 1
            elif filter3(RatiosDown[i][j],RatiosUp[i][j]):
                result[i][j] = 0
            elif filter3(UpPointsSlices[i][j],DownPointsSlices[i][j]): 
                result[i][j] = 0
            else:                       
                result[i][j] = 1
```

Comment: Just use numpy-arrays. Numba has it's own list type, but this isn't necessary and slower. Also type declaration isn't necessary.

Comment: I can only use a list of arrays (instead 2d array), because the subarrays are of different sizes. :( 
by signature I meant the declarations after the @jit